# Want Xdebug -- Using Win10 WSL Ubuntu 20, vscode and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Starting a new project in **Laravel**.  Using the latest **WSL2** under **Win10 v2004** (Apr 2020) instead of Homestead.  It's all working great.  Now I am brave enuf to want PHP breakpoints with **Xdebug**.  I have installed **Xdebug** in **Ubuntu 20** in the **WSL**.

```
~/STGdev/lv $ php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: May 26 2020 12:24:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I'm not able to get any breakpoints to work.  The big question is this --- does the **vs code Xdebug** extension use the **Ubuntu PHP** or does it require that I install an **XAMPP PHP** on under Windows?  The instructions imply that either can be used?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to enable debugging:

- Use the [VSCode Remote - WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) and let VSCode configure everything else for you
- Configure XDebug [Remote Configuration](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) in php.ini

My recommendation is using the WSL Extension method.

Keep in mind if you decided to use the Extension method, there will be a problem regarding Git not [recognizing modified files correctly](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_resolving-git-line-ending-issues-in-wsl-resulting-in-many-modified-files)

Comment: Sure, Yes, I've been using the VSCode Remote WSL extension all along since moving to WSL.  It all works fine.  Are you saying, then, that I should use the Ubuntu PHP instead of the XAMPP Win10 PHP?  I have Xdebug installed on both.

Comment: @JimDunn Yes, technically if you use the WSL Extension way, you will have an easier way handling things by using Ubuntu PHP instead of your Win10 XAMPP PHP.

Comment: **@Zombie Chibi XD**  I think I deduced that there is **not** a way in the **VS Code settings.json** to define which PHP that you want it to use.  Disappointing.  I think it just looks on the path from where it was started.

Comment: @JimDunn Have you found any workaround since?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install XAMPP, all settings are managed by your WSL with installed PHP.
I have a Laravel project with docker using WSL2 (Ubuntu 20) in Windows 10 21H2 and here is my settings to make xdebug work. I use Xdebug 2.9.8, there're some changes of text in xdebug.ini, but most of them are same.

```
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2019 18:34:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

1. If you use mount your project/files from Windows to your WSL2 environment

xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.remote_connect_back = Off
xdebug.remote_host = "host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_port=9009
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
services:
 webapp:
  working_dir: /var/www/html
  volumes:
  - ./my-project-folder:/var/www/html
```

Move in to your project folder, type `code .` to open project with WSL and then create debug file (launch.json): (enable your PHP Xdebug extension inside WSL by click on extenstion and choose 'enable')

```
"name": "Listen for Xdebug",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"port": 9009,
"pathMappings": {
    "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

2. If you use wsl file system (clone your project inside your wsl enviroment instead of mounting it from Windows):
   Settings are almost similar to (1) but you need a little additional modification:

Docker-compose.yml

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

VS Code's launch.json

```
"hostname": "0.0.0.0",
```

That's all. 2nd method is much faster than 1st method in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You have XDebug 3 installed. Version 3 of Xdebug changed the way you need to configure is's settings. The most important breaking change is that the listening port now is **9003** instead of **9000**. This is the **php.ini** configuration in my localhost for Xdebug 3 (it should work anywhere):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

Change the path to your Xdebug extension and you should be able to debug your code now.